# Google Chrome self-hosted extension does not update

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auto-update, self-hosting

**I can not make my self-hosted extension to update itself, neither automatically nor with manual updates.**

I tried:

- `Update` button at `chrome://extensions/` with `Developer mode` enabled
- `Update` button at individual extension page under `chrome://extensions` with `Developer mode` enabled

Of course before doing that I:

- updated version number in `manifest.json` and `updates.xml`
- made sure that extension ID in `app appid` and URL in `updatecheck codebase` are correct

The only way that worked is manually drag a file with new version to a tab with `chrome://extensions/`, both with and without uninstalling the older version first.

As a sidenote, the extension is installed in two of my different user profiles under the same installation of Chrome (and under the same MacOS user), but I would be surprised if it's relevant.

**How can I debug the problem? What else can I check?**

Comment: Try https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: @wOxxOm Your advice helped indeed. Would you post an answer so I can upvote it and mark as an accepted answer?